# Strictly compute RefObject from fields, but keep flexibility about the generic argument of RefObject in a hook using TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, react-hooks, ref

I want to create a simple hook that allows me to guide the generation of refs in React based on a set of fields that is provided in a function hook.

The goal is to provide a set of properties in a `fields` property, and then automatically compute the refs that needs to be created from the `references` property.

I need the refs to extend the `HTMLElement` so that I can easily focus the refs without having trouble with the type system, so all `RefObject` must extends from the `HTMLElement` class, but should not be `HTMLElement` but rather `HTMLSelectElement` or `HTMLInputElement` for instance.

For now, I have managed to make the `references` property correctly warning me whenever I try to input a property that is not included in the `fields` property which was my first goal, but now I need to be able to customize each refs inside the `references` property, which I cannot seem to achieve.

Whenever I try to access a ref with `form.references.email`, it says its type is `RefObject<HTMLElement>` when I would rather have `RefObject<HTMLInputElement>` since in the `references` property, the `email` property is created with `createRef<HTMLInputElement>()` not `createRef<HTMLElement>()`.

This is the part where I need it to be strict enough to not be anything else than `fields` but flexible enough to allow customizing the type of the ref that is bugging me and I'm not sure if this is possible using TypeScript.

I tried to use a full generic type, meaning not even having a type constraint inside the `UseFormOptions` for the `references` propoerty but it was allowing me to input more properties than needed and that is not what I want either.

I could, of course, use two userland types for the two generic arguments, but I need to achieve it without having to use a generic argument in the `useForm` hook call.

Is there a way to achieve this level of strict/flexibility inside this code in TypeScript?

```js
import React, { RefObject, createRef } from "react";

type UseFormFields = {
    [key: string]: string | number | boolean | File | FileList
}

type UseFormReferences<Fields, Reference> = {
    [Key in keyof Fields]: RefObject<Reference>
}

type UseFormOptions<Fields, Reference> = {
    fields: Fields,
    references: UseFormReferences<Fields, Reference>
}

const useForm = <Fields extends UseFormFields, Reference extends HTMLElement>(options: UseFormOptions<Fields, Reference>) => {
    return {
        references: options.references
    }
}

const form = useForm({
    fields: {
        email: ""
    },
    references: {
        email: createRef<HTMLInputElement>(),
        // @ts-expect-error
        password: createRef<HTMLInputElement>()
    }
})

const jsx = (
    <form>
        {/* @ts-ignore this should not error out */}
        <input ref={form.references.email} />
    </form>
)
```